# Mitigating RF Interferance on a PCB

Tags: pcb, rf, decoupling

I built myself a power supply and attached a scope (AC coupling) to one of the outputs to see how it would be affected by RF interference ex. a call from a mobile phone.~0.50V spike occurred, followed by ~2.5mV ripple while the call was active - and the phone close.

I'm using a screw terminal to connect panel mounted DC jack with unshielded wires, which are probably acting as antennas, and there is a 100nF decoupling capacitor at an output.

How would one mitigate RF interference in this particular scenario - without using ferrite beads? Would adding additional decoupling capacitors like in the following screenshot help or is it a waste of money and effort?

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Any tip would be greatly appreciated! :)

**EDIT:**

Scope is connected directly to the terminal.

Performing the same test with the power supply turned off yielded the same results.

**Probe used:** P6100

**Scope used:** DSO Shell

PCB should be okay in theory...it is probably the cheapo equipment I got from AliExpress. I will re-test it when I get better scope in the future.

Comment: What happens if you run the same test with the power supply turned off? How are you connecting the scope? If using a scope probe the ground lead on your probe can cause misleading readings.

Comment: I have turned off the power supply and performed the same test, results are the same. Appreciate the comment!

Comment: 2.5mV ripple is so low that I wouldn't even bother. Fun experiment: attach the scope tip to it's ground clip (maybe with a small wire in between) do the measurment again. :)

Comment: Now try looking at the scope with its probe and earth wire shorted but not connected to the power supply - what happens now?